# collectionView cells randomly gets highlighted after reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I am practicing to use collectionView to build a calendar.

My implementation is quit simple right now, mainly a copy of https://github.com/Akhilendra/calenderAppiOS/tree/master/myCalender2, just image a simple calendar. [image]

I am trying to make some advancements on it by letting users select the date they want and create a little border after the cell is selected.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    if indexPath.item <= firstWeekDayOfMonth - 2 {
        print(firstWeekDayOfMonth)
        cell.isHidden=true
    } else {

        let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2
        cell.isHidden=false
        cell.dateLabel.text="\(calcDate)"
        if calcDate < todaysDate && currentYear == presentYear && currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        } else {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
    return cell
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    addToList.append(indexPath)
    //dayCollectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}
```

The issue right now is the selected cells will jump all around my collectionView because the reuse feature. I've done some research that the way to fix this is to avoid using reloadData, but i need to flush my whole collectionView when i am forwarding to the next month.

Can someone help me out with this situation? I want to clear out the selected cells once the user move to the next month and maintain the selected cells on the month that the user did the selections.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can maintain a Boolean check for selected cells.

Comment: @user3431800 : Take a look at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

The reason cell gets randomly highlighted in your collectionView is because cell gets reused in CollectionView and TableView. When a user selects the cell you highlight the cell by changing its border width and border color but when user scrolls the same cell gets reused for some other indexPath and because you havent removed the applied effects when cell gets reused cell appears highlighted at wrong position.

**Solution :**

Because you have a custom cell class of your own, you can always use `prepareForReuse` to clear the effect applied to cell when cell gets reused.

So open up your CustomCell class and add

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 //whatever the default border width is
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor //whatever the cell's default color is
}
```

But this solves only half your problem, now though unwanted cell's will not highlight when user scrolls back to selected cell even the selected cell will not be highlighted any longer. For that to happen you need to conditionally highlight cell if it needs to be highlighted in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

So modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    if indexPath.item <= firstWeekDayOfMonth - 2 {
        print(firstWeekDayOfMonth)
        cell.isHidden=true
    } else {
        let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2
        cell.isHidden=false
        cell.dateLabel.text="\(calcDate)"
        if calcDate < todaysDate && currentYear == presentYear && currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        } else {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }

        //check if cell needs to be highlighted
        //else condition isnt required because we have prepareForReuse in place
        if addToList.contains(indexPath) {
            cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

In the code above else condition isn't required because we have prepareForReuse in place and it does the job of removing all the highlights added to cell.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out! I actually saw someone was using prepareForReuse, but it's in object-c. Your solution clears out the border or whatever the previous state of the cell is after reloadData.However, for the next part to remember which cell is selected, your solution will highlight the cell at the position no matter which month it is. cells need also to differentiate by different months. My idea is to create a fixed size of 2d arrays(size 12),containing array of array of indexpaths. Would you kindly enlighten me on how to do that? I tried dictionary as well, but stucked here,

Comment: @user3431800 : I saw you saving the indexPath in addToList array so I thought you could use it to re-highlight the cell but true that will lead to wrong cells being highlighted so u need a way to uniquely identify the cell, I believe its a calendar so I was thinking if you could save the date rather than saving the index path and later in cellForRowAtIndexPath rather then comparing indexPath if you could compare Date then your problem would be solved. I thought I would update my answer with that logic but buddy your date calculation logic is something that I am not understanding!

Comment: @user3431800 : If you dont mind do you lemme know whats that unique thing that differentiates the date being selected from other cells which are not selected, you must be having something that is specific to your calendar logic

Comment: late reply had a holiday yesterday. Happy new year to you too. As I mentioned before, I want to highlight cells for each unique month, so saving the indexPath will rehighlight the cells but it will also rehighlight the cells at the same locations for any other month. e.g. i highlighted cell 1 and 2 in Dec, if I move to Jan, cell 1 and 2 will be highlighted too. So I created a dictionary(Dictionary<Int,Array<IndexPath>>()) to save months by int and save indexpaths as arrays.It worked right now after i looked up how to get around the appending problem using a array in dictionary in swift.

Comment: @user3431800 : first of all happy new year :) Amazing, am glad to hear that you solved the problem. But buddy won't Saving a month again will solve the problem partially? Like if I select January 1 in 2018, won't it highlight January 1 2017 and 2019 as well?? How did you solve that?? Just curious to know. I think that will be a problem if you don't want the selection to be recursive in nature (like events happening on the same day every year) that's why I asked you to save the whole date. Date will be absolute n won't cause any issues never in future as well

Comment: if cellSelectedAtMonth[currentMonthIndex] == nil {
            cellSelectedAtMonth[currentMonthIndex] = []
        }
        
        var arr = cellSelectedAtMonth[currentMonthIndex]!
        arr.append(indexPath)
        cellSelectedAtMonth[currentMonthIndex] = arr
this is how people do it...it worked for me this way. I have no idea why. I am implementing deselect right now but the function won't erase my border...weird, i simply   did          cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0
            cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

Comment: user3431800 : call cell.layoutifneeded() to ask iOS to re render the cell but that will only solve the problem partially, if you scroll up or down and come back to same cell it will be highlighted again so all you have to do is to delete the year from the array in your dictionary for key indexpath and call reloadData or reload specific cell using indexpath u have :) that's all

Comment: i am doing it in  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath). This func doesnt seem to be called when I clicked on a selected cell. Looking for solution right now.  Don't bother it's solved... thought multipleselection is defaulted to be true but it's actually not so i have to manually set it to true..